# Is the infinite tower power uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

assume $f_n(x)=x^{x^{x^{.^{.^.}}}}$ with n exponents, It converges to the infinite power tower over the infinite power tower's domain. I guess it is not uniformly convergent because the graph has a significant difference between an even n and an odd n. However, proving it seems quite tricky. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean , but the power tower converges only within a small interval for $x$.